# Making a page in wordpress that doesn't affect the other pages

Tags: css, wordpress, layout

The problem is that all the pages have a `content_container` of a set width of 1056px and I want all pages to have the 1056px set width except for the home page in which I need a content container that spans over the whole page from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CSS class on the BODY tag that WP uses on either page. Write your own CSS targeting the page you want.

Answer (score 0):

add a class to the `body` of all the files (`index.php` and `page.php`) like this:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

and then target the home page with css:

```
body.home #content_container{width:100%; !important}
#content_container{width:1056px;}
```

Comment: it depends on what `content_container` is - if its a class ad a . before it `body.home .content_container{width:100%; !important}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this also:

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
//This is Home page
echo '<div id="content_container_wide">';
}  
    else { 
    // This is not a homepage
    echo '<div id="content_container">';
    }
?>
```